What are the different SigLevel options in pacman.conf?
I just learned about the pacman.conf file on my Steam Deck (SteamOS) that I can find under the /etc/pacman.conf path.
I see that my default SigLevel value is Required DatabaseOptional like this:
SigLevel = Required DatabaseOptional
LocalFileSigLevel = Optional

I know there is also a TrustAll value.

I'm slowly learning pacman and what I can do with it and I am now wondering what are all the different options that I can put there and what do each of them mean? Is it even okay to just modify the SigLevel values in the pacman.conf file?

The man page is here: https://man.archlinux.org/man/pacman.conf.5#PACKAGE_AND_DATABASE_SIGNATURE_CHECKING
